# Accessing array inside composite type in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have the following two structs. When I initialize the struct with a constructor, an array is created, but it is not what I expected.

```
using Distributions

mutable struct XYZ
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
    z::Float64
end

mutable struct Coords
    r::Vector{XYZ}
end

""" Make a structure called test that contains a vector of type XYZ 
I want to have 10 XYZ structs in the "r" Vector """

Coords() = ( rand(Uniform(0,1.0),10,3) )
test = Coords()
```

I want to access `test` by going `test.r.x[i]`, however Julia complains that type Tuple has no field r. What it does create is a 2 dimensional array of size 10x3 and I can call elements via `test[i,j]` but this is far from what I want. I want to have other arrays/variables in the composite with callable names...

I tried initializing this way as well

```
XYZ() = (rand(),rand(),rand())
Coords() = ([ XYZ() for i in 1:10 ])
test = Coords()
```

I still get the same warning. It seems like I have created a tuple rather than a composite type. How do I create a composite type that has arrays/vectors inside of other structs?

I am using Julia version 1.0.2

Comment: Oh, and `(expr)` does not create a 1-tuple -- that's equivalent to just `expr`. To actually create a 1-tuple (which you don't actually need here), write `(expr,)`, like in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are never actually calling the [inner constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Inner-Constructor-Methods-1) in `Coords()`.  To achieve what you want:

```
XYZ() = XYZ(rand(), rand(), rand())
Coords() = Coords([XYZ() for _ in 1:10])
```

But I would recommend against providing a constructor that initializes a special random layout.  Instead, you could properly [overload `rand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Hooking-into-the-Random-API-1) for `XYZ`, which gives you an array-`rand` for free:

```
julia> import Random

julia> Random.rand(rng::Random.AbstractRNG, ::Random.SamplerType{XYZ}) = XYZ(rand(rng), rand(rng), rand(rng))

julia> rand(XYZ)
XYZ(0.7580070440261963, 0.15662533181464178, 0.7450476071687568)

julia> rand(XYZ, 10)
10-element Array{XYZ,1}:
 XYZ(0.5984858021544213, 0.16235318543392796, 0.729919026616209)  
 XYZ(0.45516751074248374, 0.9667694185826785, 0.39798147467761247)
 XYZ(0.7329129925610325, 0.7725520616259764, 0.42264014343531)    
 XYZ(0.10415869248789567, 0.4193162272272648, 0.3265074454289505) 
 XYZ(0.2286383169588948, 0.7119393337105202, 0.5166340562764509)  
 XYZ(0.23011692279595186, 0.35344093654843767, 0.9488399720160021)
 XYZ(0.20464532213275577, 0.05761320898130973, 0.7694525743407523)
 XYZ(0.3022492318001946, 0.9212313012991236, 0.819167833632835)   
 XYZ(0.6331585756351794, 0.9812979781832118, 0.3969247687412505)  
 XYZ(0.6049257667248391, 0.7155977104637223, 0.5294492917395452)  

julia> Coords(rand(XYZ, 10))
Coords(XYZ[XYZ(0.633945, 0.882152, 0.750866), XYZ(0.496134, 0.241877, 0.188791), XYZ(0.267383, 0.552298, 0.613393), XYZ(0.569428, 0.503757, 0.120985), XYZ(0.822557, 0.982106, 0.37321), XYZ(0.250684, 0.701853, 0.509496), XYZ(0.886511, 0.83301, 0.381657), XYZ(0.628089, 0.00574949, 0.730268), XYZ(0.382186, 0.411701, 0.86016), XYZ(0.904469, 0.854098, 0.270464)])
```

Comment: Hello, yes changing my second versions constructors to 

`XYZ() = XYZ(stuff)` rather than XYZ() = (stuff) and changing the second constructor to
`Coords()=Coords(stuff)` rather than Coords() = (stuff)

seems to have fixed everything, thanks!